# Man pages displaying oddly

Tags: command-line, manpage

I've noticed this happening to man pages just recently:

[image: link]

It's happened a few times before but seemed to have resolved itself, through updates I imagine.
Any advice on how to fix?
Thanks.

Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Which command are you using? Which terminal software are you on?

Comment: It looks like you're viewing manpages in Vim. Did you intend to do that?

Comment: I'm using neovim as a man pager: export MANPAGER="nvim -c 'set ft=man' -"  

This is happening in all terminals that I have: st, alacritty, kitty, etc.